# Ansible: why task is skipped when: var is true

Tags: variable, ansible

From below examples 
Why DEBUG 2 has been skipped when db.x86_64.alpine.update is true 
I have been also trying "when: db.x86_64.alpine.update|bool is true" but this also fails

Variable file db.yml

```yaml
shell> cat db.yml
x86_64:
  alpine:
    update: true
    version_current: 3.14.0
    version_new: 3.15.

aarch64:
  alpine:
    update: true
    version_current: 3.14.0
    version_new: 3.15.0
```

Playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Playbook test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - ansible.builtin.include_vars:
      file: db.yml
      name: db

  - name: DEBUG 1
    debug:
      var: db.x86_64.alpine.update |type_debug

  - name: DEBUG 2
    debug:
      msg:
        - "MESSAGE"
    when: db.x86_64.alpine.update is true
```

Output when runs

```bsh
PLAY [Playbook test] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [ansible.builtin.include_vars] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "db.x86_64.alpine.update |type_debug": "builtin_function_or_method"
}

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Question:
How to display message when db.x86_64.alpine.update is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to explicitely test a boolean value. Simply use the value in the condition

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "MESSAGE"
    when: db.x86_64.alpine['update']
```

will print the message

```yaml
  msg: MESSAGE
```

The problem is that the attribute *update* collides with the method of Python dictionaries. See [Referencing key:value dictionary variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables).

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: db.x86_64.alpine['update']
  - debug:
      var: db.x86_64.alpine['update']|type_debug
```

gives

```yaml
  db.x86_64.alpine['update']: true
  db.x86_64.alpine['update']|type_debug: bool
```

Comment: works as charm! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

because your variables from file are returning a DICT...

then you can validate in this way:

```
when: db.x86_64.alpine['update'] is true
```

debugging:
db.yml is <built-in method update of dict object...>

My environment:

- Python 3.6.8
- Centos Stream 8
- Ansible installed from pip